# Tidyeval create new variable from a paste statement

Tags: tidyeval

I want a custom function to take a number, then paste a prefix in front of the number to make it a variable name, then do operations with said variable name, that already exists in the data (not a newly created variable).

This is a weird hypothetical example, but in the data I'm working with I have to do some recoding where variable names include numbers and there are sequential patterns.

```
mtcars_revid <- mtcars %>% mutate(blah1234=drat)

test_func <- function(data,initial_var_num,var_name) {
  main_var <- paste0("blah",initial_var_num)
  data %>% 
    mutate({{var_name}}:=main_var,
           {{var_name}}:=ifelse({{var_name}}<999998,{{var_name}},NA))
}

mtcars_revid %>% 
  test_func(1234,new_variable_name) %>% 
  summarize(test_var_mean=mean(new_variable_name),
            correct_mean=mean(blah1234))
```

Comment: You can subset it with `.data`, see https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask-programming.html#subsetting-the-data-pronoun